# How to process output from Ansible using local script

Tags: ansible

I want to run some command that return some data and process these data somehow with a script that is located on ansible server. How could I do that?

For example:

I want to run

```
ansible all -a "cat /etc/redhat-release"
```

Then I want to call script called `version_parser.py` (located on local ansible server, not host where ansible is executing the command) with parameters `name_of_server` and pipe the output of this call as input.

So that in reality I get something similar like

```
ssh server1 "cat /etc/redhat-release" | version_parser.py server1
ssh server2 "cat /etc/redhat-release" | version_parser.py server2
...
```

What is most easy approach to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run the remote command and store the result in a variable. Next you can run a `local_action` and execute your local script with the stored variable:

```
---
- name: Run remote command
  command: "bash -c 'ls -l /etc/init.d/a* | grep -c app'"
  register: store

- name: Run result against local script
  local_action: "shell echo '{{ store.stdout }}' | /path/to/local/parser.py {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```